# Select Customer Name From Customer Table and Count all Orders placed using orders table- SQL

Tags: sql

I have two table as defined below,

Table: **Customer**:

```
 CustomerID | CustomerName | 
 --------------------------
    1       | John
    2       | Mack
    3       | Andy
```

Table: **Orders**:

```
   OrderID | CustomerID| 
 --------------------------
    1515   | 1
    1516   | 3
    1517   | 1
    1518   | 1
    1519   | 3
    1520   | 1
```

I want to write a query to select each name and count of all orders placed by each customer using JOIN. the result will be,

```
John   | 4
Mack   | 0
Andy   | 2
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    CustomerName, Count(*) 
FROM 
    Orders
INNER JOIN 
    Customers WHERE Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

But its returning incorrect results. Please advise.

Comment: Use 'ON' instead of 'WHERE' and your problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `GROUP BY`.  I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, Count(o.CustomerId)
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o 
     ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerName;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases (`c` and `o`) make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `LEFT JOIN` keeps all customers, even those without orders.  If you don't want `0` counts, then change to an `INNER JOIN`.
- All joins should have an `ON` clause, not a `WHERE` clause for the `JOIN` conditions.
- The `GROUP BY` is also needed to fix your query attempt.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Count(*)
FROM Orders LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
WHERE Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID GROUP BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

Comment: Its producing the same result as with mine. I am using Customers and Orders Table on W3School. After using this query, only one row is selected. Please check using those tables.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CustomerName,ISNULL(_Count,0) [Count]
```

FROM Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) _Count,CustomerId _CustomerId
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY CustomerId
) A ON _CustomerId = CustomerID